# CSS Flexbox: can't scroll to overflown content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

**What I'm trying to build:**

Essentially, a collection of vertically and horizontally divs that have content, using flexbox - pretty straightforward.

**My issue:**

When I start adding content - and the content starts exceeding the window, I can't seem to reach it: I can't scroll up or down to look at overflown content.

**My build:**

This is what my `body` looks like,

```
<body>

  <div id="flex-container">

    <div class="content">

      <!-- content and other stuff -->

    </div>

    <div class="content">

      <!-- content and other stuff -->

    </div>

  </div>

<body>
```

And this is what my `style.css` looks like,

```
#flex-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:100%;
}

.content{
  width:75%;
}
```

I have tried setting `overflow` properties to no avail. If I don't add the `height:100%;` the content doesn't get centered vertically.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the problem is. I've put a bunch of content in those divs and I can scroll with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `overflow: auto;` to the div, this will add a scroll bar to see the extra overflown content